# How to sum of the digits of an Int

Tags: arrays, swift, integer

I have an `Int` like this

```
let num: Int = 123
```

Now I want to split it into digits like `1, 2, 3` and sum them in order to get `6`.

Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to create a _Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Given this

```
let number = 123
```

### You can

```
let digitsSum = String(number)
    .characters
    .flatMap { Int(String($0)) }
    .reduce(0, combine: +)
```

### How does it work?

`String(number)`

The first instruction convert your `Int` into a `String` so now we have `"123"`

`.characters`

This extract an array of `Characters` so the output is `["1", "2", "3"]`

`.flatMap { Int(String($0)) }`

This convert the array of `Characters` into an array of `Int` so `[1, 2, 3]`

`.reduce(0, combine: +)`

Finally each element of the array of `Int` is combined with the `+` operation. So 1 + 2 + 3.

Comment: works perfectly fine, thanks a lot!! but i need to learn the logic behind these formulas. thanks!

Comment: @DogukanInal: I added a more details.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you do it.

1. Define a variable `s` for the sum, initially set to 0.
2. Define `n` as your number, initially set to 123.
3. Compute `n % 10` to extract the last digit. % is the modulus operator. Add that to `s`.
4. Use integer arithmetic: `n = n / 10` to remove that last digit.
5. If `n` is zero, you're all done. Else go back to (3).

Comment: its a very simple way for me to understand. thanks a lot!

Comment: This is really the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Summing the shifted ASCII values of the character representation of your number

As an alternative to [@appzYourLife:s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38327305/4573247), you can make use of the `utf8` property of `String` to directly access the ASCII value of the characters in the `String` representation of your number

```
let number = 123
let foo = String(number)
    .utf8.map { Int($0) }
    .reduce(0) { $0 + $1 - 48 }
```

Since you know that you're going from a given number to a `String`, we know for certain that the characters in the `String` can all be represented, without loss, using `utf8` encoding (even by ASCII encoding, in fact). The ASCII values of characters `"0"` through `"9"` are represented by the (`UInt8`, here) numbers `48` through `57`, hence the shift of `-48` in the `reduce` operation above.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert number to characters and enumerate it:

```
let numbs = 123
let str = "\(numbs)"
let a = str.characters.reduce(0) {
    return $0 + Int("\($1)")! // Note this is an explicit unwrapped optional in production code you want to replace it with something more safety like if let
}
print("A: \(a)")
```